# ODP.NET OracleCommand optional parameter never getting default value

Tags: vb.net, oracle, odp.net

When I'm calling a function from a PL/SQL package, there is a IN optional parameter (Date) with default value of SYSDATE.

When I execute my commmand, I don't have a choice but to add the parameter. Even if there is no value set, the function always receive null as the entered value, so it never affects the default value.

```
            Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "PACK.RefreshData"

            Dim param1 As New OracleParameter()
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
            param1.ParameterName = "p_date"
            param1.DbType = DbType.Date
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

            param1 = New OracleParameter()
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            param1.ParameterName = "po_errorCode"
            param1.DbType = DbType.String
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

            param1 = New OracleParameter()
            param1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
            param1.ParameterName = "po_errorDescription"
            param1.DbType = DbType.String
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param1)

            con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

In another question, somebody said the command property `BindByName` set to true works only for regular queries, not storedProcs. So what can I do to call the function without passing a value with my IN parameter?

Here is the Stored Proc header

```
Procedure RefreshData
(
  p_date IN DATE := SYSDATE, 
  po_errorCode OUT  varchar2, 
  po_errorDescription OUT   varchar2
);
```

N.B. : I'm using Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 4.112.4.0

UPDATE : Here is the explanation taken from the oracle thread, from my answer below :

I think what it boils down to is that DervieParameters is deriving parameters for all of the proc params, even though they have default values, and that seems to me to be the correct behavior. Once you have parameters in the collection, if you don't assign a value to them, null will be passed.

What you probably need to do is

1) the best option, is not to use deriveparameters in the first place, and manually build the parameters collection, adding parameters for only the things you don't want to have default values:

DeriveParameters incurs a database round-trip and should only be used during design time. To avoid unnecessary database round-trips in a production environment, the DeriveParameters method itself should be replaced with the explicit parameter settings that were returned by the DeriveParameters method at design time.

2) If you want to continue using DeriveParameters, remove the unwanted parameters from the OracleParameters collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have been able to find a way to call the procedure with this thread :

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2248928?tstart=0

Here is my corrected code :

```
            con.Open()
            cmd = con.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.CommandText = "Pack.RefreshData"
            cmd.BindByName = True

            OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd)
            cmd.Parameters.RemoveAt(0) 'I remove the optional parameter 

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Then I retreive my OUT parameters

```
            Dim outPrm1 as String = ""
            If cmd.Parameters("po_errorDescription").Value IsNot Nothing Then
                outPrm1 = cmd.Parameters("po_errorDescription").Value
            End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have default-value parameter not at the tail of the parameters chain you should perform *named parameters call* to avoid passing this default-value parameter. I think your data provider doesn't support this call type, so  you should wrap  your call  in anonymous pl\sql block like this :

```
begin
    PACK.RefreshData(po_errorCode => :po_errorCode, po_errorDescription=>:po_errorDescription);
end;
```

and then do what did before in VB code (ofcourse you `CommandType` will be `Text`).

Another solution is to move your default-value parameter to the end of parameters chain like this:

```
Procedure RefreshData
(
  po_errorCode OUT  varchar2, 
  po_errorDescription OUT   varchar2,
  p_date IN DATE := SYSDATE 
);
```

Comment: Changing the parameter orders in the procedure changes nothing on the ODP.Net side, as it still throws a missing parameter exception. I am able to call the procedure via a `CommandType = CommandType.Text` and manually creating the call, however the OUT parameters are left out (I can't get their OUT values).

Comment: So, what's the problem with wrapped call methid? Do you have any errors?

Comment: I haven't tried that solution, however I think it can be a good turnaround. In my situation, I prefered to find a solution in the .Net code first as a db script would be more complex to execute in all our client databases.